# Ошибка 500 при получении данных ajax через функцию

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Есть код на js, который обрабатывает нажатие кнопки:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: {plan:1}
    }).success(function(output) {
        ...
        console.log(output);
    });
```

Обрабатывается на php так:

```
$plan = $_POST['plan'];
if ($plan == 1) {
   $user_id = logged_user()->getId();
   $current_user_department_id = 123;
   $array = array("one" => $user_id, "two" => $current_user_department_id);
   echo json_encode($array);
} else {
   ... остальной скрипт, который загружает страницу еще до вызова ajax ... 
}
```

Пока я не получаю переменную "user id" все прекрасно работает, даже если укажу статично, но как только получаю данные через функции `(logged_user()->getId())` консоль в js выдает 500 ошибку :

> (POST http://.../script.php 500 (Internal Server Error)).

При этом сам PHP нормально выводит массив, внутри того же условия.

Comment: @kills

1) что выведет страница при прямом запросе?
2) что в валится в error.log?

Comment: @Etki
1) Если я правильно понял, что прямой запрос это чисто на PHP то он возвращает массив с верными данными. Даже больше, ранее эти данные подгружались как глобальные переменные при загрузке страницы, но теперь из-за огромного кол-ва выгружаемой информации это сильно влияет за загрузку страницы и поэтому пришлось делать через ajax
2) Я совсем забыл про лог...:
#1 ERROR: Error: Undefined index: plan in '/.../script.php' on line 2 (error code: 8)
#2 ERROR: Error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in '/.../ObjectMembers.class.php' on line 131 (error code: 2)

Comment: @kils, проверьте в консоли (браузера), как отправляется аякс-запрос. Похоже, что в `$_POST` нету никакого ключа `plan`.

Comment: @Etki

посмотрел во вкладке Network, передается "plan=1", а вот изначально при загрузке страницы скрипт не вкурсе что такое plan я думаю в этом тоже может быть причина.. проверю

Comment: @Etki

Ругается видимо на тот индекс, что в POST передается, проверил в консоли, передается именно через POST и индекс верен.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, проблема именно в `logged_user()->getId();`
[Решение на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633593/fetching-logged-in-user-data-in-activecollab-by-this-logged-user)

Я могу только догадываться, что такое `logged_user`, stackoverflow, и google подсказывают, что это `activecollab`, если да, то [вот ссылка на api авторизации пользователя](https://activecollab.com/help/books/api/authentication.html).
Проблема именно в том, что либо функция `logged_user()` не возвращает объект, который имеет метод `getId()`, либо внутри самого `getId()` происходит какая-то ошибка. Но мне кажется, что `logged_user` возвращает null или false, или еще что-то, но никак не объект. Распечатайте сначала `var_dump(logged_user());` и посмотрите, что вернется, если не вернется объект, разбирайтесь, почему.

Тогда попробуйте сделать немного иначе:

```
        $plan = $_POST['plan'];
        if ($plan == 1) {
            $logged                     = logged_user();
            $user_id                    = $logged->getId();
            $current_user_department_id = 123;
            $array                      = array(
                "one" => $user_id,
                "two" => $current_user_department_id
            );
            echo json_encode($array);
        }
```

Я конечно не думаю что это что-то кардинально изменит, но с другой стороны на некоторых платформах работает `var_dump(debug_backtrace()[0]);` а на некоторых нет, приходится записывать результат в переменную и уже с переменной обращаться.

Comment: var_dump(logged_user()); выводит очень много информации, если разместить вне условия и ничего не выполняется внутри условия. Проверил на других функциях, любая не работает, как будто не видит функции и классы.
activecollab в системе не используется, одноименная функция, видимо.

Если внутри условия в качестве переменных не использую функции, то все работает и ошибок в лог не валится...